# Dynamic datasource in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, connection-string

I am working on a report which will pull all sysadmin login's from each server. So I used below data source properties and created parameter names:

```
servername ="data source=" & Parameters!Servername.Value & ";initial catalog= master"
```

above solution working fine in SQL Server Data tools but when I deploy in report server I am getting error on connection error's like below.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'dSource_DbOwner'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) Format of the initialization string does
>   not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Please let me know all your inputs

Thanks, Ven

Comment: You might be trying to set the entire connection string inside the servername property.  You posted "servername=", so try it with just the server name instead of the entire string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS can be annoying sometimes with plain text. I would suggest going into the connection manager and using the wizard. I believe it is a button with build on it to the top right hand side of where you are inputing this text. That will create the connection easily and it wont spit and sputter at the connection string.